# Trying to delete a user using html links with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have some users with different privileges, the admin being able to delete users.  I am trying to delete these users from the database using html links...but my real question is why isn't it even vardumping the user to begin with?

ROUTES

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/user/home' , array('before' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UserController@userHome'));
    Route::get('/tech/home', array('before' => 'tech', 'uses' => 'TechController@techHome'));
    Route::get('/admin/home', array('before' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@adminHome'));
    Route::get('/admin/show/users', array('before' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@adminShowUsers'));
    Route::delete('/admin/delete/{$id}', 'AdminController@adminDelete');
});
```

ADMINCONTROLLER

```
 public function adminShowUsers(){

        $users = User::all();

        return View::make('admin/showUsers')->with('users',$users);

    }

 public function adminDelete($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        var_dump($user);



    }
```

showUsers VIEW

```
<?php

foreach($users as $user){

    $id = $user->id;

    echo "<a href='/admin/delete/" . $id . "'>". $user->username ."</a>";
    ?>

<?php

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that everything up to that point is working? Is the route extracting the `$id` parameter?

Comment: If I echo the ID in in the adminDelete function i still get an error, is that what you mean?

Comment: Ok well, i changed the route to Route::get('/admin/delete/{id}', 'AdminController@adminDelete'); and it worked

Comment: Yes, if the id is not coming through, then your find function won't return a record, which would explain why the vardump isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

A `Route::delete` route matches only requests that use the **HTTP DELETE** method. Now the problem is that you can't make a "normal" link, that uses that method. (Same goes for POST and PUT)

As you might know we can use a HTML form to send a POST request. However HTML forms don't support the DELETE method. But Laravel closes that gap by automatically sending a `_method` parameter with the request when using `Form::open`. [In the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form)

So you could use a form pointing at your route with only a submit button inside:

```
echo Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/delete/'.$id, 'method' => 'delete'));
echo Form::submit($user->username);
echo Form::close();
```

Or, much simpler, (and I see in the comments you already discovered that) you could just change to route to `Route::get`. Still I wanted to write this answer to let you know what exactly was happening and what the possible solutions are.